# Delta Lake with Azure Data Lake Store Gen2

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2

recently I started working on Azure Data Lake Store Gen2 and Delta Lake. I am having permission issues writing delta to ADLS Gen2.

***StatusCode=403
StatusDescription=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
ErrorCode=AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
ErrorMessage=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.***

Anyone have encounter this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like writing as delta does not like abfss://source-data@.dfs.core.windows.net/. Not sure whether it's the abfss protocol or the 'dfs'. Writing to blob using 'wasbs' and 'blob.core.widnows.net' have no issues.